# How to create n degree Identity Matrix with mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How to make n degree Identity Matrix with ***mathematica....***

Set id[n] :=????? -> Perform the id[2] (Shift+enter)-> Get {1,0},{0,1}(2X2 Identity Matrix)

not using command( IdentityMatrix, DiagonalMatrix, Inverse, SparseArray).

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Please read through some of the guides to ask better questions and therefore get more useful answers. You could start here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sounds like a homework question. Why not use the right tools?

Answer (score 1):

```
degree = 4;

id = Reverse@Sort@Select[Tuples[{0, 1}, degree], Total[#] == 1 &];

id == IdentityMatrix[degree]
```

> True